# React Native web view overlaying bottom-bar ,and top bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am adding a web view in a screen. This screen has bottom bar, top bar, and drawer. How to add webview in such a way that it will display over the entire screen overlapping all the components. I have tried adding styles and all but it's not working. I am using createBottomTabNavigator and createDrawerNavigator for bottom bar and drawer.

This is what I have tried, I can still see the bottomTab and header. I have also removed the bottom and it works ofc, but I don't want to remove it, just want to display over it.

```
export default function Home({ navigation }: any) {
  const windowDimensions = useWindowDimensions();
  const webviewHeight = windowDimensions.height;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com/' }}
        style={[styles.webview, {height:webviewHeight}]}
      />
    </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        position: 'relative',
      },
      webview: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        zIndex: 999,
      },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Th problem most likely lies in your styling. you can try this. If this dosent work , please let me know:

```
   webview: {
    flex:1,
    height:"100%",
    width:"100%",
    zIndex: 2,
  },
```

also if you want to use `position` styling then try this way:

```css
     container:{
     flex:1
     },
     webview: {
        flex:1,
        position: 'absolute',
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%",
        zIndex:2
        
      },
```

you need to remove position relative from parent component , then only it will take full space

Comment: Thank you for your reply, no this is not working, I can still see the bottom bar and the headers. @Basit Mit